# algorithm with linear time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

We say that if an algorithm takes p time for an input size of n (here, p is a polynomial in n, and the degree of p is y), then the algorithm's complexity is O(n^y).

In the image, when n is very large it does not seem to matter much if it's x^2 or 2x^2. but, it clearly seems to matter if it's x or 2x. So, then why do we approximate, something like 3000x to x?
[image]

thank you

Comment: Talking about the multiplicative constants in the time complexity of an algorithm does not make sense unless you fix the details of the computation model. See the [linear speedup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_speedup_theorem).

Comment: Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/52174/683